# Is there any way to load an entire directory at once using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, save

I'm using libgdx to make an Android game and I'm in the process of adding sound fx and I'm wondering if there is any way to load all of the sound files in a directory at once instead of a one by one.

I load them into the asset manager like this and I can't seem to find any way to load the entire folder.

loadassets.load("directory/folder/filename.mp3", Sound.class);

Comment: When you say "all at once instead of one by one", do you mean in parallel, or do you mean that you want to avoid explicitly listing individual files?

Comment: I meant listing individual files, and it appears someone posted a solution using for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two days ago I wrote a little utility class to do exactly that. Not only for sound files, but for any kind of resource.

```
public class AssetFinder {

    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private FileHandleResolver resolver;

    public class AssetDescriptor {
        public String folder;
        public Class<?> assetType;

        public AssetDescriptor(String folder, Class<?> assetType) {
            this.folder = folder;
            this.assetType = assetType;
        }
    }

    private Array<AssetDescriptor> assets = new Array<AssetDescriptor>();

    public AssetFinder(AssetManager assetManager, FileHandleResolver resolver) {
        this.assetManager = assetManager;
        this.resolver = resolver;

        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("music", Music.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("sound", Sound.class)); // You could remove all but this one
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("skin", Skin.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("texture", Texture.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("atlas", TextureAtlas.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("font", BitmapFont.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("freetype", FreeTypeFontGenerator.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("effect", ParticleEffect.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("pixmap", Pixmap.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("region", PolygonRegion.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("model", Model.class));
        assets.add(new AssetDescriptor("level", TiledMap.class));
    }

    public void load() {
        for (AssetDescriptor descriptor : assets) {
            FileHandle folder = resolver.resolve("").child(descriptor.folder);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                continue;
            }

            for (FileHandle asset : folder.list()) {
                assetManager.load(asset.path(), descriptor.assetType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using it is simple and works like this:

```
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
AssetManager assets = new AssetManager(resolver);
AssetFinder assetFinder = new AssetFinder(assets, resolver);
assetFinder.load();
assets.finishLoading();
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Though I do have a question, how do I define the filepath of the folder I want it to search in? Or does this just scan the entirety of the assets folder/sub folders for anything that matches the string argument?

Comment: `resolver.resolve("").child(descriptor.folder)` first resolves the root (in case of internal files, that's the assets folder) and then searches for a folder with the given name in that root folder. If you want to use absolute paths, you could change that to `resolver.resolve(descriptor.folder)`.

Comment: @David Be careful, this works in your IDE, but I just found out that when you package your desktop app into a .jar file, this stops working. It's because for some very weird reason Java decided that folders in the classpath are not reported as folders. In this case nothing will be loaded because `folder.list()` won't return any children anymore. F*CK Java!